# Selenium module `NoSuchElementElement` exception [PYTHON]

Tags: python, selenium, exception

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: #loginUsername
```

I used selenium module to automate the login process of some websites and when I executed the program, it throws `NoSuchElementException` while I tried all the `find_element_by_*` methods ( by id, by class, by css selector, by text, by name attr ) but, still I get this error and I don't know how to make this program error-free so, is there any other way to debug the program??

Comment: Share the URL. If not possible, update the question with HTML.

Comment: Sounds like that's in iframe, please check for iframe.

Comment: no iframe or what so ever it was just wrapped inside a form tag and a fieldset tag

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so posting an answer. I assume any one of the below reason can be the cause.

- Please check the element `xPath` `id` etc. in chrome console to make sure you are using right `locator`
- There is not enough time you are giving for element to be accessible. Please use `explicit` wait.
- May be element is `present` on DOM but not `visible` when you try to perform action.
- From error message I can see you are using `css` selector `#loginUsername`. I assume you are not giving `tag` name like it suppose to be `input#loginUsername`

Answer (score 0):

I understand that there are no iframes from what you said above.

Make sure that you wait for the element to be loaded and made available before you call find_element(...).

Do something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:/chromedriver/94/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://yourwebsite.com")

# use By.XPATH, By.CLASS_NAME etc. depending on the 
# element you're referring to
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'loginUsername')))
login = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginUsername')
```